# WebApi Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm just starting out with ASP.NET MVC WebApi and EntityFramework and wanting to use a data-first model to bring objects out of an existing database. This works fine but it takes a decently long time to bring back the data with only 500 records because the data is related over several tables. I want it to bring back only the main table in my pull for performance in searching, so I do something like this:

```
    // GET: api/Cases
    public IQueryable<Case> GetCases()
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        return db.Cases;
    }
```

However, it's still pulling back all of the related tables. Any idea how to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<Case> GetCases()
{
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    return db.Cases.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

Comment: That brought me back this error in my JSON return: "innerException":{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"When an object is returned with a NoTracking merge option, Load can only be called when the EntityCollection or EntityReference does not contain objects." I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: Updated my reply